# how long can it take me to get 1 BTC on mining speed 30.9945H/s and 72.99451H/s respectively

Tags: mining-hardware, mining-profitability

im new to this biticoin mining, i justed to know is it going to earn me anything soon where my mining speed is at 30.9945165416H/s and 72.9945165416H/s really? how long can it take me to get 1 BTC

like for;
30.9945165416H/s how many days

72.9945165416H/s how many days

Comment: Do you really mean H/s? Not GH/s or TH/s?

Comment: how can i increase the speed using my computer to meet at least GH/s. what should be my average speed to make 1BTC atleast in a month and kindly note that im using Cryptotab browser to mine

Comment: @ChibubiJackson You can't. You're trying to mine bitcoins without a bitcoin miner. See my answer -- you have a completely inappropriate tool and are competing against people who have the right tools. You will never, ever win.

Comment: what startup hardware can i use and how much can it be?

Comment: like this one Bitmain Antminer S9i, and how many BTC can i mine in a month?

Comment: kindly advise which one of theses two can i buy 
 https://shop.bitmain.com/product/detail?pid=00020181217184315223R2qdxwHM06D0     or   https://shop.bitmain.com/promote/antminer_s15_asic_bitcoin_miner/overview

Answer (score 5):

It would never, ever happen. The increase in difficulty and the reduction in mining reward would mean that you would never, ever accumulate anywhere near 1 BTC with a mining speed that low. You would need to be more than a billion times faster.

Mining is perfectly competitive. Trying to mine with hardware like that is like trying to win a race to build a suspension bridge across a massive river using teaspoons and toothpicks when other people have flat beds full of steel and steamshovels.

**Update**: "*kindly advise which one of theses two can i buy ...*"

Why? Why would you want to enter a business you don't understand? I don't understand tailoring, so I'm not going to go out and buy the stuff to have a tailoring business. Having a bitcoin mining business requires you to get everything right because it is absurdly competitive. Were you to just get an S9i and hook it up in your home, you'd lose $45/month. And that assumes you don't need additional air conditioning to get rid of the 1.3Kw of heat it generates.

**Update**: I just read their FAQ -- they're not mining bitcoins at all, "*In fact, CryptoTab software is mining Monero(XMR) and then converts them to Bitcoins in accordance with the current exchange rate, that is why your balance is displayed in BTC.*".

I re-did the math using Monero, and I got a best case yield of minus $6/month. The exact amount depends on your electricity cost. That assumes you personally keep 100% of your mining reward, which I'm pretty sure you don't since you're in someone's downline and are paying for conversion to BTC and whatnot.

It seems like an obviously bad idea though. What's the benefit of combining the mining program with a browser? What conceivable advantage does that have over a separate mining program? And there are obvious downsides -- if I want to change mining programs, mining pools, or which coins I'm mining, I have to change browsers!

Comment: how can i increase the speed using my computer to meet at least GH/s. what should be my average speed to make 1BTC atleast in a month and kindly note that im using Cryptotab browser to mine

Comment: You can't. You have a computer and are competing against people with bitcoin miners. You are competing with people who have equipment that is more than a billion times more efficient than what you have. That is utterly pointless.

Comment: whaat startup hardware can i use

Comment: @Chibubi You'll need to buy specialized Bitcoin mining hardware.

Comment: like this one Bitmain Antminer S9i, and how many BTC can i mine in a month

Comment: kindly advise which one of theses two can i buy 
 https://shop.bitmain.com/product/detail?pid=00020181217184315223R2qdxwHM06D0     or   https://shop.bitmain.com/promote/antminer_s15_asic_bitcoin_miner/overview

Comment: @ChibubiJackson See updates. Why are you trying to enter a business you know nothing about that is *perfectly* competitive? That just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: you keep slapping me in my face kikikiki whats wrong with you.jackson wanted to make money but your Apostolic kind of advice has just made his ass find a place down

Comment: okay i hear you, i need some quide to do. i was miss led by this new browser CRYPTO BROWSER https://get.cryptobrowser.site so thought i could get it work well with the hardware like you tried to put it. i dont know what i can do because in two days i haave only managed this 
0.000001597194BTC

Comment: and yeah, it came to me brand new without fixed ideas like your tailoring concept kikiki

Comment: @ChibubiJackson You saw a business pitch involving getting your friends to get their friends onboard and you thought that sounded like a good idea?! Has there ever been an MLM scheme that wasn't a scam? Here's the obvious biggest red flag ever -- nowhere do they give you any clue what your earnings might be from *ANY* source other than getting other people to use the system. How can that work? Someone has to actually generate revenue for their to be anything to flow up from a downline, right?

Comment: @ChibubiJackson: The largest private Bitcoin mining company in the world recently started shutting down some of its Bitcoin mining farms. If they can't make a profit in the current market, you have to be much smarter than them to do so. You need very cheap electricity and a large investment in equipment that may only be economically viable for a short while. It isn't the sort of business you should go into without long detailed careful preparation and planning.